# Updating an SObject in a loop in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm trying a very simple flow as an example/training. Given a list of Accounts I want to set the Shipping Street to the Billing Street if Shipping Street is empty. The flow is a little ragged as I've learned about how not to feed records to it, but the main logic is this:

[image]

Here's the debug:

[image]

We can see in the debug that the address value was copied within the loop. Then when it comes to save we can see that `ShippingStreet=null`.

So where is it going?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variable scope issue. Your address is getting set only within the context of the loop iteration, but it is not actually updating the values in the source Account list, if that makes sense. So if you updated each Account individually inside of the loop (which you shouldn't do) then the updates would work. But as soon as you leave each loop iteration, the updated value is lost.

I'd create a new empty Record Collection Variable, and inside each iteration of the loop, add a record to this new collection. Make sure you include the Account Id and the Address. Then update that Collection Variable instead of updating your initial Collection of Accounts.

I'd love to hear from others if there's a better way. But in programming this is all about whether the variable is passed into the loop 'by value' or 'by reference'. In this case, it's only being passed in by value.

Answer (score 2):

It's a variable scope issue. The answer is given [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_loop.htm&type=5) (*Note the line in bold*).

> A loop uses a loop variable to store the values for the current item
> in the collection. When the loop finishes examining an item, it copies
> the field values for the next item into the loop variable. To
> reference each collection item in elements along the loop path, use
> the loop variable. **To keep changes made along the loop path, add the
> loop variable as an item in a new collection variable**.

A sample of how to use the loop and store the changes in a collection is given [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_loop_example.htm&type=5), so you may want to check this out.

You don't necessarily need to implement this logic via loop for your use case. You can get it done directly using the `Update Records` element. Refer to the screen shot below where I've defined the filter conditions and the field values to be set. Depending on your overall flow logic, you might have to tweak whether you are using a separate collection variable in the `Update Records` element or let the flow use its default bulkification over `$Record` variable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There was I hoping it behaved like a normal loop in other programming languages and passed by reference. I'll make those changes and test again.

Comment: Good find on those documentation links @arut! My answer was lacking those.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and did something similar to get around it. In the loop I copied the record ids to a text collection variable instead of assigning a value.
Then In the update element, i specified my conditions manually by saying 'RecordId' IN text collection variable.

Set fields manually

Field To update = Value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).